# I am new to android. I wish to use android service for blocking call only when the service is started

Tags: android

This is the code should be run only when the service is running. And the service should be stopped in some other part.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{

    this.context=context;
    this.intent=intent;

    if (!intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"))
        return;


    else
    {
            number = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

            if (Callblockactivity.blockList.contains(new Blacklist(number))) {
                System.out.println("i");
            }

            else {

                    disconnectPhoneItelephony(context);
                    return;

            }
       }
    }
```

Now, the service should be started in mainactivity as follow.

```
 if (speed >10) {
  //service should be started.
  }

     else {
  //service should be stopped
   }
```

Please help with this.

Comment: What problem have you met? Can't you start a Service? Or don't know how to recognize whether your service is running?

Comment: I don't know where to start the service, whether inside the condition or when the activity is created. I need to check whether the service is started, and if it is started, the call block code should be run. kindly help with this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you want to use a Service here? Services are meant in order to do some work in background. Is it necessary for you?

Comment: Actually my application is intended to block the incoming call only when the speed of the user is greater than 10mph. What should I use in android to accomplish this?

Comment: yes, I think Services are appropriate here

Comment: for starting a Service: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService%28android.content.Intent%29

Comment: I have started a service but in which activity should i check whether my service is running and if so, it the block code should run.

Answer (score 0):

use [startService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService%28android.content.Intent%29) to start a Service. Use [stopSelf](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#stopSelf%28%29) or [stopService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#stopService%28android.content.Intent%29) to stop your service.

And you may use a static boolean variable inside your service in order to keep the flag whether the service is running.
Instead of that variable also  you may  [dynamically register](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver%28android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter%29)  a receiver when you start your service, and [unregister](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#unregisterReceiver%28android.content.BroadcastReceiver%29) it when you stop the service.

Comment: How can I start a service inside the onReceive() method

Comment: I suppose it's better to start a service and to check the current speed inside of it. You may register a receiver when the speed is higher than your threshold (10) and unregister it when the speed is lower. But if you want to start a service from onReceive(), just call this.startService(...)